# My first Chrome extension can't find default_popup page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm following this tutorial to create a simple Hello World extension for Chrome:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html
I have followed all the steps in that tutorial, and although I get to see the icon in the toolbar button, when I click the button I see a popup document with this error:

> **This webpage is not found** No webpage was found for the web address:
>   chrome-extension://mblkllehamdcncminlelggjfcbmkflbj/popup.html Error 6
>   (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

I have the popup.html and popup.js files in the same folder than the icon
Here's my manifest.json contents:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? (I've been googling for quite a while without success, looks like the point where I'm stuck at is no problem for anyone else...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `htm` extension instead of `html`?

Comment: the problem was that the popup.html file name had a blank space at the beginning; i removed and it worked as expected, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooops...

Forget about this lame question.

My *popup.html* file had a blank space at the beginning of the file name ( *" popup.html"* ) because of the copy-paste. I removed it and it worked perfectly.